# How to add a template in to Symphony projects

Tags: content-management-system, symphony-cms

I am new in Symphony and would like to add a new design. Here I have attached the file which I want to integrate in the user side.  How is this possible?!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use [templates](https://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/page-templates/). Make sure you read through that page.

Chapter 2 of the [Say Hello to Symphony tutorial](https://www.getsymphony.com/learn/tutorials/view/say-hello-to-symphony/) deals with templates, and is a nice way of getting to grips with how it works.

Hopefully this will give the basic idea of how to control the HTML output using XSLT. You will then need to create your CSS to style your HTML.